# How to install IBM db2 ODBC driver in Windows 7 - 64 bit?

Tags: sql-server, db2, odbc, driver

I need to connect to remote DB2 from local SQL Server 2008 R2. I don't want to use linked servers. So I am searching for download and trying to install IBM DB2 driver, as Microsoft ODBC driver for DB2 comes with Host Integration Server is expensive.

Comment: No free solution?? I need to access the database in the DB2 server. If it is not free to get odbc drivers, can you suggest any other way to connect to DB2 other than linked server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download DB2 clients for your DB2 version from here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053

Client software is free.

Answer (score 7):

Both answers are correct, but only have the links to were the answers are.

1. download the correct driver (called fix pack most of the time) you need from [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053)
2. extract the contents of the zip file to `c:\program files\IBM` , I unzipped it in `c:\program files\IBM\clidriver`
3. open a command prompt as administrator and change to the directory you just created and then go in the bin folder
4. execute the following commands to install and register the odbc drivers

   ```
   db2oreg1 –i

   db2oreg1 –setup
   ```
5. check your odbc manager if the drivers are installed, this is depending on the version you selected (32 bit or 64 bit)

for the 32 bit version open your odbc data sources 32 bit otherwise open the odbc data sources 64 bit.

---

To open odbc data sources in windows versions 7 upwards

1. press the windows key
2. type `odbc`
3. click on the version you need (32 bit or 64 bit)

Comment: For some reason, the hyphen that I copied from the above commands did not work. The above commands were simply showing me the usage instructions. So I had to manually type "-i" and "-setup" after the commands. It worked then. Thanks!