# IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER :: SQL1390C The environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not defined or is invalid

Tags: db2, odbc, db2-400, db2-luw, polybase

I've followed several guides online and I cannot install IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER on Windows.

I have downloaded the [driver from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-db2-fix-packs-version-db2-linux-unix-and-windows) and installed (which was quite a roller-coaster).

If I follow [guide1](https://www.ryslander.com/how-to-install-and-configure-db2-odbc-driver/) or [guide2](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/370019?language=en_US) the result is the same:

```
SQL1390C The environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not defined or is invalid
```

[image]

**Note:** this is my `C:\Program Files\IBM` folder and as you can see there is no `bin` folder

[image]

Not sure if `db2oreg1.exe -setup` is still mandatory, things might have changed.

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions described at the [Configuring the IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=environment-configuring) link? Just in case about the Installation: [Installing the IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI software on Windows operating systems](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dsd-installing-data-server-driver-odbc-cli-software-windows-operating-systems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkBarinstein I found where the problem was.

I've followed this guide [How to install IBM db2 ODBC driver in Windows 7 - 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341961/how-to-install-ibm-db2-odbc-driver-in-windows-7-64-bit) and I downloaded the wrong package: I downloaded the **universal_fixpack** instead of the **client**.

I realized that when I saw the two folders in the Download directory:

[image]

So I uninstalled the **universal_fixpack** and installed the **client** and the installation was successful.

Comment: BTW, `IBM Data Server Client` and `IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI` (which you mentioned in your question) are different client types. Refer to the [IBM Data Server Client and driver types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=overviews-data-server-clients) link for detailed description.